# Width not filling all of the LinearLayout

Tags: android, width, android-linearlayout, fill

This is my first time working with android design so have a little patience with me. This project was not made by me, I'm simply tiring to fix some bugs and so sometimes it gets difficult to change stuff, because lots of stuff is already "together".

I have a Master_Layout that is divided in a fragment and a FrameLayout. My ListRows layouts are going to be displayed on the left of the MasterLayout. Then I have a Details_Header_Layout and Details_Layout that are displayed on the right. The problem here is that I can't get the whole width on the right side, that's why my scroller is not on the far right, right? Here's an image to show the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciyf4rbh4ogvikr/scr.png?dl=0

[image: a]

The stupid thing is that on the Adjustment tab I have the same code for the Layouts (But I don't have a Header Layout on Adjustments), where you choose on the left some data and it shows on the right the details. And on the Adjustments tab everything is ok, I have the whole width and the scroll bar is on the far right!

Can you tell me if there's any problem with my Measurement data layouts? I don't understand since is the same as the Adjustments.

**Master Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <fragment
        class="AppMobile.Android.DataMemoryMasterFragment"
        android:id="@+id/data_memory_master"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/data_memory_details"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Detail Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/datamemory_detail_layout"
    android:background="@color/white" />
```

**Detail Header Layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/DataMemory_Detail_Header_Layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:src="@drawable/Data_Memory_OK"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="32"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_normal_text"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_samplename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Samplename"
        android:textColor="@color/btn_normal_text"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datamemory_details_id"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error! The layouts are okay!

The guys that did this, on the method OnCreateView they were doing a "new LinearLayout.." with wrap content. Simply removed that line of code and now I have the whole width on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
Detail Header Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/DataMemory_Detail_Header_Layout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/white">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:src="@drawable/Data_Memory_OK"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="32"
    android:textColor="@color/btn_normal_text"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/datamemory_details_state"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/datamemory_details_samplename"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Samplename"
    android:textColor="@color/btn_normal_text"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/datamemory_details_id"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
```

Master Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white">
<fragment
    class="AntonPaarMobile.Android.DataMemoryMasterFragment"
    android:id="@+id/data_memory_master"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/data_memory_details"
    android:layout_weight="4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Detail Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/datamemory_detail_layout"
android:background="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Why not taking the time to explain what and why you changed some things in the layout xml. you are now just handing out some code. How should the OP learn from that?

Comment: No, the detail layout in the design view becomes all black.

Comment: You're right.
You just have to compare the values of the android:layout_width,android:layout_weight between answer to the question from this figure out the mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said. I just have to compare the values of android:layout_width and android:layout_weight between what?

Comment: I answered to Daniel Martinus.